# Display multple charts with asp.net mvc chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts, bar-chart

I am trying to create 2 charts with Asp.Net MVC chart control on a cshtml razor page. First chart works fine always but second chart will not display. What may be the issue with Chart initialization.

First Chart which works fine. But after adding same code one more time it fails to show the second one.

```
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] {"a","b","c"},
            yValues: new[] {"1","2","3"})
        .Write();
}
```

second one copy paste of first with different initiaization, data

```
@{
    var myChart1 = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title1")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee1",
            xValue: new[] {"a1","b1","c1"},
            yValues: new[] {"3","2","1"})
        .Write();
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. Did you get any error? Can you share also `output` please?

Comment: output has only first chart displayed. If I swap code by moving bottom chart code to top and top chart code to bottom, only top chart code is visible in the output. Somehow only one charts code which is on top is displayed. I also changed the css to see if charts re rendered on same positions but it is not the case.

Comment: Chart helper renders image. Here is the documentation:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart#displaying-charts-inside-a-web-page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart#displaying-charts-inside-a-web-page) . First you need to create a page `ShowChart.cshtml` and then you need to create other pages: `MyChart.cshtml` and `MyChart2.cshtml` and move your chart code to these pages. To show your charts use `img` like these  `<img src="MyChart.cshtml" /> <img src="MyChart2.cshtml" />`